# How to copy + paste from a random text box generator? Using python, webdriver selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to copy + paste an random email generator that is generating from a text box! I just can't get it to copy or paste it! Anyone got any idea?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

elementlist = []

while True:
     driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')


     #Get email
     driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/');
     time.sleep(5)


     element = driver.find_element_by_id('mail')
     time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: We really need more information to understand what your problem actually is.

Comment: Please add some more details with your code snippet and screenshot of page HTML code if possible

Comment: I put in a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information we have right now, I would say you have 2 options to handle the issue.

#### Option 1

Get the text from the email box and save it in a variable.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('mail')
emailtextvalue = element.text
```

And use the "emailtextvalue" variable value for pasting to somewhere else.

```
import pyperclip
...
element = driver.find_element_by_id('mail')
emailtextvalue = element.text
pyperclip.copy(emailtextvalue)
...
pyperclip.paste()
```

#### Option 2

Click on the actual copy button and use the clipboard value.

[image]

```
import pyperclip
...
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-clipboard-action='copy']")
emailtextvalue = element.click
...
pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: I will try that! Give me a sec!

Comment: It says:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sudo.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'